# Whats the meaning of "It is not trivial to ..."?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

I came a cross in a book with: "HATEOAS is not trivial to implement, but ...".

I know that "trivial" means unimportant and not serious. But I don't understand above sentence(`...is not trivial...`)!!!

Comment: If something is not trivial to do , then the action of doing it is not trivial. That is, it is important, serious, complicated, time-consuming, etc. A house is not trivial to build, a serious illness is not trivial to treat, a large meal is not trivial to cook.

Comment: If you understand what 'trivial' means, please explain what you do not understand about 'not trivial'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HATEOAS is a computational technique that is complex and not easy to deal with unless you are a specialist. The point of the sentence you give is that it emphasises the difficulty of creating or implementing HATEOAS, despite any apparent simplicity of the concept. It is therefore not trivial.